# How can I open any specific program in Java?

Tags: java, running-other-programs

I want to open 2 different browsers with the same link. I have found how to open the default browser, but I want to open a non default browser as well, and I can't seem to find a way.

Comment: You could use Runtime.exec(...) as other answers suggest. But it seems like a hacky solution. There may be a way to do it in SWT APIs though.

Comment: I suggest you look into [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org). It provides lots of possibilities for browser automation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open `non default` browser, you'll need to know where it is installed and what browser. After that you can open it using the following command:

```
Runtime rt = null;
rt =  Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("<PATH TO FIREFOX>\\firefox.exe <WEBSITE TO OPEN>");


<PATH TO FIREFOX> = Path to whatever browser you need to open.
firefox.exe = Launcher for the browser.
<WEBSITE TO OPEN> = Website URL you are trying to open.
```

To open private browsing: Use tag `-private-window`

Example:

```
rt.exec("<PATH TO FIREFOX>\\firefox.exe -private-window <WEBSITE TO OPEN>");
```

Comment: Ty this is exactly what I was looking for. Is there any way to also open a private version of the browser. There are different codes for each broser, i know, but where would I put that in the code?

Comment: It would just be another argument.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Yup I did do that, I had to give it a few minutes. Thank you so much it solved exactly what I needed